# Rogue query orderAsc with variable field according to its name

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

I am using Rogue/Lift Mongo record to query MongoDb. I am trying to create different query according to the sort field name. I have therefore a string name of the field that I want to use to sort the results.

I have tried to use `Record.fieldByName` in OrderAsc:

```
...query.orderAsc (elem => elem.fieldByName(columnName).open_!)
```

but I obtain "no type parameter for orderAsc".

How can I make it working? Honestly all the type programming in Rogue is quite difficult to follow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot dynamically generate a query with Rogue easily. As solution I used Lift Mongo Db that allows the usage of strings (without compile checking) for these kind of operations that requires dynamic sorting.